# how to apply physics using physi.js with mirror.js on the plane in three.js

Tags: html, three.js, game-physics, physics-engine

I create mirror plane using mirror.js  in three.js.
now i want to apply gravity over that plane. i have try this code but get error

```js
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 300, 300 );
  var groundMirror = new THREE.Mirror( renderer, camera, { clipBias: 0.003, textureWidth: WIDTH, textureHeight: HEIGHT, color: 0x777777 } );
    var Material = new Physijs.createMaterial(groundMirror);
    var cube = new Physijs.BoxMesh(planeGeo,Material,0 );
    cube.add( groundMirror );
                scene.add(cube);
```

Comment: You are using a version of three.js that is a year old. Use the current version if possible.

Comment: i had changed three.js with latest version but not any changes takeplace

Comment: Is this what you really want to do? http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html

Comment: yes and i execute the code from the link completely but i want to know that how can apply physics over it..so after it i try              var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 300, 300 );
  var groundMirror = new THREE.Mirror( renderer, camera, { clipBias: 0.003, textureWidth: WIDTH, textureHeight: HEIGHT, color: 0x777777 } );
    var Material = new Physijs.createMaterial({ envMap: groundMirror});
    var cube = new Physijs.BoxMesh(planeGeo,Material,0 );
    cube.add( groundMirror );    but i get error so can you please correct this code?

Comment: Correct your title, add physijs tag, explain the error, clean up your formatting. Wait for someone who know physicjs to respond... Or delete the question and start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CubeCamera is a bit of a waste for a single plane, you could always use a single perspective camera and align it with your plane. The basic idea is to take plane normal, position your camera behind the plane in aligned on the normal going through the center of the plane, and orient it (rotate) to be aligned with the normal. Make sure you set near value of your camera to be the same as distance between the camera and the plane, so that reflections can be captured at to the point of contact. Question on scale is resolved by ensuring your viewport is the same size at the plane.

For reference, have a look at he CubeCamera source code:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/CubeCamera.js

#### EDIT:

After looking through examples again, i found that Slayvin has implemented just that:
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html

here's a relevant snippet:

```
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 100.1, 100.1 );

// MIRORR planes
groundMirror = new THREE.Mirror( renderer, camera, { clipBias: 0.003, textureWidth: WIDTH, textureHeight: HEIGHT, color: 0x777777 } );

var mirrorMesh = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeo, groundMirror.material );
mirrorMesh.add( groundMirror );
mirrorMesh.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
scene.add( mirrorMesh );
```

Comment: you mean to replace that cubeCamera with perspective camera ?

Comment: yes! indeed. The idea is to have a camera look through your plane, you then use your renderer to draw scene from perspective of that camera, and you use result from the renderer to draw a texture for your plane. Sounds complicated, give it a try - it's not as bad as you think! :)

Comment: have you seen my post?

Comment: i had tried with your given code and execute them successfully but at the time i remove all physics from the plane. now i had to implement physics over it.. thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

correct it by changing
var Material = new Physijs.createMaterial(groundMirror.material);

```js
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 300, 300 );
  var groundMirror = new THREE.Mirror( renderer, camera, { clipBias: 0.003, textureWidth: WIDTH, textureHeight: HEIGHT, color: 0x777777 } );
    var Material = new Physijs.createMaterial(groundMirror.material);
    var cube = new Physijs.BoxMesh(planeGeo,Material,0 );
    cube.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
    cube.add( groundMirror );
```

Comment: Why don't you do it now?